# Bending stress wave resulting from a lateral impact on a beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics, impact

I want to approximate a bending stress wave resulting from a lateral impact on a beam which is on one end fixed.

[image]

According to Roarks 16.3-3 I can estimate a compressive stress wave from one mass impacting on a bar with one end fixed:

[image]

- $E$ is Young's modulus
- $V$ is the material stress wave velocity
- $v$ is the impact velocity

My first idea is to put the impact energy in the sentence of Castigliano:
$$U = 1/6*(M^2*l)/(E*I)$$

solve for bending stress

$$\sqrt{18*U*E/(l*A)} = \sigma_{bend}$$

- $l$ is the length of the beam
- $A$ Section of the beam
- $U$ is the impacts energy
- $I$ Second moment of area
- $M$ Bending moment

But this ignores the mass ratio of the impact and the stress wave velocity, so I think the values I get are too high. Does anyone have an idea how I can go about this? Could I simply scale the stress with the mass ratio like this:
$$\sqrt{18*U*E/(l*A)}*\frac{1}{1+m_1/m_2} = \sigma_{bend}$$

- $m_1$ is the mass of the beam
- $m_2$ is the impacting mass

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do or correlate with. The main difference between the stress from impact and static bending stress of a cantilever is the velocity (speed) of the force applied and the associate energy, U = mV^2/2 = F*d (d is the deflection due to impact). Are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The impact scenario in Roark's formula is axial (not lateral, as in your drawing).  Imagine impact is very slow, almost static.  Will the axial stress solution give you the bending stresses?

Comment: Near me, it wouldn't matter if the impact is static, quasi-static very quick. You have a ball and it hits the beam, with a force. If you could calculate the force, then you can directly use the bending formula because it reduces to a simple cantilever beam system subjected to load at its end. After the impact completes, you could know the stresses within the beam and deflections of it from analytical equations. Ofcourse, that would last as long as the impact is there (even for milliseconds). As soon as the impact finishes, there are no forces and hence no deflections or stresses.

Comment: So am I wrong in correlating the description of a **stress wave** with the stress resulting from strain energy?

Comment: @clockworker, look, impact is not as easy as you think. When an extremely rigid ball for example impacts a beam, then all of the energy during that impact will be taken by the beam i.e. you can actually translate the initial energy to a force which is completely taken by the beam. Moreover, the region of impact i.e. the region where force is acting will also remain constant from the start of impact to the end.

Comment: However, if you consider a very flexible ball (like a tennis ball) then you have track how much energy is taken by the ball itself and how much by the beam. Since action is equal to reaction, therefore the force will be the same acting on it (I am not sure if this value of force will be affected if the ball becomes flexible). Nevertheless, the impact area now keeps on changing from the start of the impact to the end. So you have to keep track of the region (which is continously changing during impact) and apply force there.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq That was helpful: Ignoring the impactors flexiibility is a major idealization. In Roark's equation both bodies flexibilites are one-dimensional. If I want to model a two-dimensional body, like a beam, I have two make sure, that the rigid body assumption for the impactor is justified.

Comment: @r13 I think you were right that I was trying to reinvent the wheel: In the end I was surprised I got the equation for strain energy after putting the impact energy in the sentence of Castigliano :)